# Issue with the background responsiveness

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am working on : http://brand-prestige.com/signup/
The problem I am facing is the logos scatters around doesn't stay at same place but goes behind the form while resizing the window.How can I make them stable?what cs do i need to use?
PLease help!

Comment: Can you post your current code? A jsfiddle would also help

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
background-position: center center;
background-size: cover  cover;
```

Add this to your body element.

Comment: The question has been answered 3 times already, so there is no need to post another answer. Also, this code does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to centre your background image horizontally and align it to the top vertically. At the moment it's aligned to the top left as that is the default.

```
background: #EAEAEA url(../imgs/bg.png) 50% 0%;
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting a jsfiddle would help people in getting an answer over to you.

But looking at your source code, try adding this for the effect you are after:

```
.authenty {
    background-position: center center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use background-position:center on the .authenty class. This will make the logo background stay in place and goes around your form.